# exclusive xor/or operator?

Tags: c, arrays, xor

We haven't done this in the lecture yet, and I'm trying to figure out how to substitute my (if/else) for a single exclusive OR order.
Can somebody explain to me how it should be done?

(Full Code is showing "LED-DISPLAY" written in #'s)

```
void toggle_pixel_v2(unsigned int pixel_number, void *adr) {
char *pc = (char *)adr;
int ioff = (pixel_number-1) / 8;
int ibit = (pixel_number-1) % 8;
if ( pc[ioff] & (1<<ibit) ) pc[ioff] &= ~(1<<ibit);
else pc[ioff] |= (1<<ibit);

}
```

Comment: In C, consider the operator `^`

Comment: As in `pc[ioff] ^= (1<<ibit);`

Answer (score 0):

Let `a` be the bit at position `b` in `A`.
`A &= ~(1<<b)` clears `a`. `A |= (1<<b)` sets `a`. Both operations leave the rest of `A` unchanged, because `x & 1 = x` and `x | 0 = x`.

With `A = pc[ioff]` and `b = ibit`, your code clears `a` if it is set and sets it if it isn't. That's the result of an exclusive or: since, in `(1<<b)`, only the bit at position `b` is set, the result of `A ^ (1<<b)` is `A` with `a` toggled (because `x ^ 1 = ~x` and `x ^ 0 = x`).

So the two following codes are equivalent:

```
if (A & (1<<b))
    A &= ~(1<<b);
else
    A |= (1<<b);
```

```
A ^= (1<<b);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed explanation!